# How to import a file so if I run files in diffent directoris within the project each will get the correct import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

This is a question about python imports.

Suppose I have a folder structure like this:

```
Project1  
|  
|--app  
    |--__init__.py  
    |--app.py  
|--debug_routines  
    |--__init__.py  
    |--debug.py  
|--main.py
```

I want to be able to run main.py and app.py.... and any other file in the project potentially and the import to just work?

main.py

```
from app.app import App
from debug_routines.debug import dprint
import os

def main():
    dprint("main start")
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
    dprint("main end")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

app.py

```
import tkinter as tk
#from debug_routines.debug import dprint ## This one works if running main.py from parent directory.

#from ..debug_routines.debug import dprint ## Does not work when ran from app.py

from debug_routines.debug import dprint


class App(tk.Tk):
#class App:
    def __init__(self):
        dprint("app.init start")
        super().__init__()
        dprint("app.init end")

def main():
    dprint("Start of app.main()")
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
    dprint("End of app.main()")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

debug.py

```
import os

def dprint(theString):
    if __debug__:
        print("dprint(" + os.path.basename(__file__) + ": " + theString + " )")
```

My question is about imports as it pertains to running `main.py` and `app.py`.
I can setup the import in app.py so that when I run `main.py` the import works but if I then run `app.py` the import fails.

Is there an import syntax that works so that in a project I can write the import in such a way that I can run different files and they still get the import correctly?

As an example when I have the `app.py` import for the debug_routine set to `from debug_routines.debug import dprint`, if I run main it works. If I run `app.py` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sdb1_hdd_1tb/Projects/Python/Tkinter/PictureApp/src/app/app.py", line 6, in <module>
    from debug_routines.debug import dprint
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug_routines'
```

I have also tried putting an `__init__.py` file in the `Project1` folder and it did not do anything.

Edit:

Am I just better off creating a separate `test.py` file for each dir/`module`? Maybe go with the `if/else if` import statement? I could even minimize the `if/else if` by just including an if in the app.py file in the header section and in the main function i could do the relative imports?

Seems like the import system is not robust? (surprises me)

Comment: *How* are you running the different files exactly?

Comment: @deceze I have tested from the Project1 directory using 'python main.py' and 'python ./app/app.py'. I have also ran 'main.py' and then went into the 'app' directory and ran the 'app.py' file using 'python app.py'

Comment: Basically you just need to run your files “correctly”. There’s no universal way to import packages that magically works from anywhere and everywhere. If you run your files as modules, that’ll work differently and better for your purposes: `python -m app.app`.

Comment: @deceze I tried `python -m ./app/app.py` and `python -m  app.py` (from withing the app dir). The first gave me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug_routines'` and the second gave me `/media/sdb1_hdd_1tb/Projects/Python/Tkinter/PictureApp/venv/bin/python: Relative module names not supported`

Comment: You would need to be in the directory *above* the `app` dir (so `app` is a directory in your current work directory), and do `python -m app.app`. Again, `-m` accepts a module name, not a file name. The current working directory is automatically used to search for modules.

Comment: @deceze You should post your previous comment as an answer so I can accept it. 
Using `python -m app.app` from the Project1 directory allows me to do the development that I need.

Answer (score -1):

You can put the imports inside a if condition. And I think you have to, to avoid any circular imports. I dont understand why you would import the main.py file with only the main function but anyways.

```py
# app.py
if __name__ == "__main__": # check if we are starting app.py or app.py is imported
   # we run app.py
   from ..debug_routines.debug import dprint
else:
   # we import app.py. The path base is now wherever the import comes from.
   from debug_routines.debug import dprint
```

How you import is based on your root dir, determined by your python file you run. So the code above just checks for that. It could be that you would be required, in order to get it to work, to check not only the `__name__`, but also the root dir to get all imports to work as the executing script could not be `main.py`.

The init.py does matter if you import a folder/directory, basically representing a package. And helps to manage the namespace. In your case you import the function of a file in the folder, the init file doesn't do match there.

I don't know why you want to be able to run every file. I never saw any project build like that. So maybe it would be worth reconsidering your project structure.

[https://realpython.com/python-import/#:~:text=In%20Python%2C%20you%20use%20the,while%20keeping%20your%20projects%20maintainable](https://realpython.com/python-import/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20you%20use%20the,while%20keeping%20your%20projects%20maintainable). that link could help you understanding what's going on.

Comment: I had thought of something like this. To me this would seem to not be "pythonic"?

Comment: More pythonic would only be importlib i guess

Comment: I'm looking for a solution where I can do incremental building and testing in a module and then quickly pivot to testing it with the main application. Coming from the C world I would of liked a way for python to allow importing with a minimal of cpu time needed.

Comment: i think then writing the imports for main.py and running it from the project1 dir should work. so you run `python app/app.py`. that should result always in the same search path and resolve the import conflicts. Basically what @deceze already suggested

Comment: Calling main.py from the Project1 directory can work but I cannot, from my attempts, get a call to app.py to work. This when using `python main.py' vs. `python ./app/app.py` 

Having the same include statement does not seem to work.